# What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Tags: meaning, grammar, differences

> 1. He isn't **meant** to be disrespectful.
> 2. He didn't **mean** to be disrespectful.

Answer (score 3):

Both are grammatically correct, but they mean different things.

> He didn't mean to be disrespectful.

This would mean that he was disrespectful without intent.  It's the negative of "He meant to be disrespectful".  (When negating verbs in the simple past with `didn't`, use the base form of the word, `mean` in this case, not the inflected form you use for a positive sentence, `meant`).

> He isn't meant to be disrespectful.

This uses a slightly different meaning of 'mean' and the sentence would indicate that his purpose was not to be disrespectful.  For instance, if you created a robot to help people find their way in a store, and they perceived it as being disrespectful you might say "I'm sorry, he isn't meant to be disrespectful" to indicate that you didn't mean for that to happen.

Comment: Haha - Great minds think alike!

Answer (score 2):

They are both correct but they have different meanings.

> He isn't meant to be disrespectful.

This means, "We don't want/expect/intend him to be disrespectful."

Another paraphrase is "He isn't supposed to be disrespectful."

There is a definition of the idiom "[be meant to](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/be%20meant%20to)" from the *Collins Cobuild English Dictionary for Advanced Learners*, 4th Edition, on Reverso.

> He didn't mean to be disrespectful.

This means: "His intention was not to be disrespectful."